# How to find the word wrap points of Resizable Textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, textarea

I have a textarea which is resizable. When users resize the text area...I would like to recreate the text exactly on an image using php intervention. TextArea's do not automatically add new line characters when words are wrapped. How do I calculate where the new lines has to be added when the text area is resized?

I need to create the image with text wrap and also I need to save the data for later use so that I can display with the same word wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a textarea, you can't... maybe if you use a `<canvas>`, subscribe the resize event of the textarea for resize the canvas with the same dimension, subscribe the textarea change event for insert the same text in the canvas, with same text dimensions, same line height etc etc... you can use that canvas for create the image, without php intervention.

Don't know if it could work, is untested and it's just the first idea that I had reading your question, if you decide to proceed in this way, let me know if it works!

Comment: yes.. canvas would have been a good option. But the main problem is I need it as text and it needs to be saved in the db for later use. And also my page do have lots of scripts already.

Comment: You can use both, textarea and canvas, as I wrote in my response, if you don't want to see a double text of course you can make the canvas not visible, but you can use it for the creation of the image on submit and upload it together with the text of the textarea